# Multiple datepickers on a form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to have 102 datepickers on a page where people will indicate a start date and an end date for an ad listing.

This works, but I have to create 102 instances of "datepicker"
datepicker
datepicker1
datepicker2
etc

Not a huge deal to do it that way, but wonder if there is an easier way to do the script

I'm using the jquery datepicker

This is a portion of my current code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker3").datepicker();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker4").datepicker();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker5").datepicker();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker6").datepicker();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker7").datepicker();
});
</script>


<input type="checkbox" id="Alabama" name="alabama" value="X">
<label for="Alabama"><b>Alabama</b></label><br>
Start <input type="text" name="AL_date_s" value="" id="datepicker2" size="15" /> 
End <input type="text" name="AL_date_e" value="" id="datepicker3" size="15" /><br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Alaska" name="alaska" value="X">
<label for="Alaska"><b>Alaska</b></label><br>
Start <input type="text" name="AK_date_s" value="" id="datepicker4" size="15" /> 
End <input type="text" name="AK_date_e" value="" id="datepicker5" size="15" /><br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Arizona" name="arizona" value="X">
<label for="Arizona"><b>Arizona</b></label><br>
Start <input type="text" name="AZ_date_s" value="" id="datepicker6" size="15" /> 
End <input type="text" name="AZ_date_e" value="" id="datepicker7" size="15" /><br>
<br>
```

Comment: Give them all the same class `<input type="text" class='datepicker'` and then once `$(".datepicker").datepicker();`

Comment: Sweet! Works like a charm